# Office 365 Access Token Retrieval for Accounts with Two-Factor Authentication Enabled

Tags: c#, .net, web, office365, access-token

I have an application built with Angular for the frontend, a .NET 7 web API for the backend, and a SQL Server database. I am attempting to integrate Office 365 functionality to read/write emails and Teams chats.

Upon logging into my app, I'm trying to get a token in the backend using the O365 credentials of the user as follows:

```
public async Task<string> RequestO365AccessToken(string email, string password)
{
    string grant_type = "password";

    var SecretValueDbObject = await context.OfficeSecretValues
                               .Where(a => a.OfficeSecretValueId == 1)
                               .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    var client_secret = SecretValueDbObject.Value;

    // These reassignments overwrite the method parameters. Consider removing or renaming them.
    var email = "ADDING THE EMAIL HERE";
    var password = "ADDING THE PASSWORD HERE";

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, 
                 "https://login.microsoftonline.com/1eda1ee1-2c51-412e-8654-4901e72243c7/oauth2/v2.0/token"))
        {
            try
            {
                var contentParams = string.Format("grant_type={0}" +
                                      "&client_id={1}" +
                                      "&client_secret={2}" +
                                      "&userName={3}" +
                                      "&password={4}" +
                                      "&scope={5}",
                                      grant_type,
                                      "a3360e20-298a-41a7-9814-ef627328426b",
                                      client_secret, email, password,
                                      Uri.EscapeDataString("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"));

                request.Content = new StringContent(contentParams, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        var resultJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var cust = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MicorsoftToken>(resultJson);

                        return cust.access_token;
                        // Successful response handling can be added here
                    }
                    else if (response.Content != null)
                    {
                        var errorDetails = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        return "NT";
                        // Error handling can be added here
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Exception handling can be added here
            }
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

This approach works when I use an email that does not have 2FA enabled. However, it fails for emails with 2FA enabled. After obtaining the access token, I use it to call Microsoft Graph APIs to fetch emails.